# MySql check if the dates range overlaps

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

```
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
| id | percentage | from_date           | to_date             | type_id | tag      |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
|  1 |      10.00 | 2022-04-01 00:00:01 | 2022-04-05 23:59:59 |       1 | discount |
|  2 |      10.00 | 2022-04-06 00:00:01 | 2022-04-10 23:59:59 |       1 | uplift   |
|  3 |      10.00 | 2022-04-12 00:00:01 | 2022-04-15 23:59:59 |       1 | discount |
|  4 |      10.00 | 2022-04-20 00:00:01 | 2022-04-25 23:59:59 |       1 | uplift   |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
```

I'm trying to create a function in php for user to create discount/uplift the prices. The user can select the from date and to date from date picker.

Now I want to restrict the user from creating discount/uplift if the selected date range falls between existing range.

Given the above table, there is a discount on the products from 2022-04-01 to 2022-04-05 and 2022-04-12 and 2022-04-15. So user can't create any discount/uplift for this range.

As above there is an uplift in the prices between 2022-04-06 to 2022-04-10 and 2022-04-20 to 2022-04-25 and user can't create any discount/uplift for this range.

```
SELECT * FROM `discounts` WHERE type_id = 1 AND (`from_date` <= $fromDate AND `to_date` >= $toDate);

SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE type_id = 1 AND '$fromDate' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date

SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE type_id = 1 AND '$toDate' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
```

All above queries are working.

But there is a window to create discount/uplift between `2022-04-11 00:00:00` to `2022-04-11 23:59:59` and `2022-04-16 00:00:00` to `2022-04-19 23:59:59`

Is there any way to check the above condition.

**EDIT**

My question is:
How can I validate if the user input `fromDate` as `2022-04-16` and `toDate` as `2022-04-18`, because it's a valid date range which does not fall under any range in the table. So user can create record to this range.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? check whether it is possible to create in the selected range?

Comment: You can implement the restriction with a  MySql trigger. Is creating a trigger the problem you are stuck at?

Comment: @Serg Can I check it in SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can check like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `discounts` 
WHERE type_id = 1 
  AND `from_date` <= $toDate AND `to_date` >= $fromDate;
```

For `$fromDate = '2022-04-11 00:00:00'` and `$toDate = '2022-04-11 23:59:59'` the query will return nothing which means that this datetime interval is available.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac4561fe7beaed74799906cde52287ae).

Comment: Ah, I see. Just inverting from date and to date will do the trick. Great, it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: What about daterange when discount start in busy period and end in free? its return nothing and its wrong result. Is not it?

Comment: @PavloMezhevikin can you reproduce what you claim that it is wrong in the demo I provide in my answer?

Comment: My apologies, I rechecked again and the answer was excellent.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert data depending on condition. The CTE in the below query emulates a source of  parameters in question

```
insert into tbl(id, percentage, from_date, to_date, type_id, tag )
with params as( 
   select timestamp '2022-04-16 00:00:01' fromDate, timestamp  '2022-04-18 00:00:01'  toDate
)
select 5, 11 ,fromDate, toDate, 1, 'discount'
from params p
where not exists(
  select 1 
  from tbl t
  where type_id = 1 and p.fromDate < t.to_Date  and t.from_Date < p.toDate)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. @forpas answer resolved the issue.